# Merging Assemblies

Tags: dll, assemblies, merge, ilmerge

I m working on a project which contain about 17 projects in it, means 17 DLL's. i want to merge some assemblies together. after googling i found ILMerge . is  Ilmerge good ? n how to use it? can anyone tell me ? i tried it but so many errors came when i try to run the .exe.

Anyone ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to merge all of the assemblies? What I mean is, do you know why it is sometimes a good thing to have many assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run ILMerge by first passing the "primary" assembly, and then all of the other assemblies. Use the `/out` option to specify the output assembly, and use the `/targetplatform` option to specify the .NET target version (and directory containing the reference assemblies, usually under `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`).

More details are in the `ILMerge.doc` file installed along with ILMerge (usually at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.doc`).