# Packaging files into one executable (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I developed a small project using C# and got everything working perfectly.
The only problem is that this app will be regularly sent via emails, therefore I'm trying to assemble all the files as one executable. The user will only have to open and see one executable, which will load the needed files and start the application.

The app does not use any external libraries. The only `.dll` file is for the `IWshRuntimeLibrary`.

The files that need to be assembled:

[image: Files]

Note that I know that some files can be removed (svhost etc.). However this won't help because I'll still have more than one file. Also I've tried some free assemblers online but none of them worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562709/merging-assemblies)

Comment: You only need a small selection of those files. All `.pdb` and `.vshost` files shouldn't be distributed

Comment: Have you considered embedding this dll as resource into your exe? Please refer to:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource

Comment: I tried ILMerge but it didn't work

Comment: `It didn't work` is probably the worst error description ever.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer build was successful but app was not functional

Comment: Do you have any required settings in your `app.config`? Does the merged assembly work if you leave all other files in the same directory? Are you using any other external resources? Have you tried [debugging the merged Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064741/how-do-i-debug-into-an-ilmerged-assembly)? etc ...

Comment: Note that you do NOT need the "vshost.exe.config" file.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know, and several other files can be removed. I got to a point where it is working with 4-5 files

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer There are no required settings. The app is very simple. The merged assembly works if i leave the other files. When i debug it also works. If i remove the files it boots but some functions are not being accessed.

Comment: @NBousaba Have you tried any of the answer below?

Comment: @SarveshMishra Not yet, I will work on it in a bit

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, select the reference of `Interop.IWshRunctime...` and in the property window, change the value of `Embed Interop Types` to `True`.

This will not generate a separate dll for Interop Types.

> PS: This is not a generic solution, but works with Interop Type only.

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://github.com/Fody/Costura in the past. Nuget install `Install-Package Costura.Fody` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/)

Description about what it does from the source:

> Take all assemblies (and pdbs) that have been marked as "Copy Local" and embed them as resources in the target assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for a method to merge some assemblies and resources into one executable file.
Custora.Fody, ILMerge, Obfuscators with assembly merging feature are some examples that can be used for this purpose.

You can find some answers here:
[Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)
[How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)
[List of obfuscators for .NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET)

Answer (score 0):

If this is not about security reason, I would create the directory structure as follow:

```
- root
└　Startup.bat
└　lib
    └　DiagnosticsSwitch.exe
    └　DiagnosticsSwitch.exe.config
    └　DiagnosticsSwitch.exe.manifest
    └　Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll
```

---

And inside the Startup.bat

```
"lib/DiagnosticsSwitch.exe"
```